# Kendo UI Validation for Razor instead of Html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, unobtrusive-validation, kendo-ui-mvc, kendo-validator

I use Kendo validator in my MVC application and **want to change the position of validation message from below to right of the input**. Although the html code of Kendo UI validation appears right of the input, the same code shows validation message below the input instead of right of it. Is there any mistake or how to convert it to razor? Please note that there is no space between "required" and "validationmessage" in razor code, but when using it as html code an error encountered. Any idea?

You might have a look at: http://jsbin.com/kubohuniki/1/edit?html,output

**This line shows validation message on "right" of the input:**

```
<label>Label RIGHT</label>
<input id="Name" class="k-textbox" required validationmessage="required field" />
```

**This line shows validation message on "below" of the input:**

```
 <label>Label BELOW</label>
 @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class="k-textbox", requiredvalidationmessage="required field"  })
```

Comment: requiredvalidationmessage seems written combined

Comment: Did you even look at your  JSBin link?

Comment: @sakir I know it is combined, but it is not supported to write separately on razor.cshtml page and when using like that an error encountered. So, I need to know how to use this code in razor view? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Pluc Yes, I know. But in my project it is working and the only problem related to my TextBoxFor is that it shows the validation message just below the input instead of near to the input. So, I need to know how to use this code in razor view? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u try to use single quote like this { @class="k-textbox", requiredvalidationmessage='required field'  }

Comment: In that case encountered "Too many characters in character literal". I have a look at the internet, but not found a proper solution.

Comment: try this new { @class="k-textbox",required='true',validationmessage="required field"  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (updated)

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Question, new { @class = "k-textbox",


required = "true", validationmessage = "required field" }) 

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question)
```

Comment: Sorry, but still not working :( On the other hand, the html attributes below works for Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBoxFor() in the project. How can I adapt this html attributes to textBoxFor()?

Comment: .HtmlAttributes(new { data_validmask_msg = "Reguired field!..",                         required = "required" })

Comment: Could you please send the link?

Comment: I see the validation message below the control in Firefox and Chrome. However I want the message is shown near to the control. Many thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Ok, it is understood that the problem is related to use "**Kendo()**.TextBoxFor" instead of "TextBoxFor". It is really strange. Many thanks for your help. Could you please update your answer code above so that the other people could use the correct way directly. I will select it as answer of course :) Here is the working code:

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Question, new { @class = "k-textbox", required = "true", validationmessage = "required field" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question)